# Increase Execute Duration of Procedure When Using Variables in WhereClause

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, variables, stored-procedures

I Have a procedure executed in SQL Server 2008 R2, the script is:

```
DECLARE @LocalVar SMALLINT = GetLocalVarFunction();

SELECT 
  [TT].[ID],
  [TT].[Title]
FROM [TargetTable] AS [TT]
LEFT JOIN [AcceccTable] AS [AT] ON [AT].[AccessID] = [TT].[ID]
WHERE 
(
  (@LocalVar = 1 AND ([AT].[Access] = 0 OR [AT].[Access] Is Null) AND
  ([TT].[Level] > 7)
);
GO
```

This Procedure executed in `16` seconds.
But When I change the Where Clause to:

```
  WHERE 
(
  ((1=1) AND [AT].[Access] = 0 OR [AT].[Access] Is Null) AND
  ([TT].[Level] > 7)
);
```

The Procedure Executed in less than `1` second.

As You see I just remove the local variable.

So where is the problem? Is there any thing I missing to use local variable in where clause? any suggestion to improve execute time when I using local variable in where clause?

**Update:**

I also think to add an `if` statement before script and split the procedure to 2 procedures, but I have 4 or 5 variables like above and use `if` statement is so complex.

**Update2:**

I change the set of `@LocalVar`:

```
DECLARE @LocalVar SMALLINT = 1;
```

There is no change in execute time.

Comment: I think the optimizer is messed because of the local variable.

Comment: How long does `GetLocalVarFunction()` take to execute?

Comment: @RahulTripathi, I Update the Question, when I replace the local variable with 1=1 the execution time is less than 1 second

Comment: @Oded I'm not sure but is that the case, I thought the `@LocalVar` Set 1 time and used more in where clause, Am I wrong?

Comment: @Oded I update the question, and change the set of `@LocalVar` there is no change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use use local variables in `WHERE` filter then it causes **FULL TABLE SCAN**. The value of the local variable is not known to the SQL Server at compile time. hence SQL Server creates an execution plan for the largest scale that is avaliable for that column.

As you have seen that when you pass `1==1` then SQL server knows the value and hence the performance is not degraded. But the moment you pass a local variable the value is unknown.

One solution may be to use **OPTION ( RECOMPILE )** at the end of your SQL query

You can check out the [OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2008/11/26/optimize-for-unknown-a-little-known-sql-server-2008-feature.aspx)

Comment: It seems the `Option(Recompile)` is Effective, I'm going to do the full test.

Answer (score 2):

When you use a local variable in WHERE optimizer doesn't know what to do with it.

You may check this [link](http://connectsql.blogspot.gr/2012/07/sql-server-how-local-variables-can.html)

What you could do in your case is run your query with displaying the actual plan in both cases and see how SQL is treating them.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using the `@LocalVar` as a branch condition, as follows:

- If `@LocalVar` is 1 then apply a filter to the query
- If `@LocalVar`is 0 then return an empty result set.

IMO you would be better off writing this condition explicitly, as then SQL will be in a position to optimize separate plans for the 2 branches, i.e.

```
DECLARE @LocalVar SMALLINT = GetLocalVarFunction();

IF (@LocalVar = 1)
    SELECT 
      [TT].[ID],
      [TT].[Title]
    FROM [TargetTable] AS [TT]
    LEFT JOIN [AcceccTable] AS [AT] ON [AT].[AccessID] = [TT].[ID]
    WHERE 
    (
      ([AT].[Access] = 0 OR [AT].[Access] Is Null) AND
      ([TT].[Level] > 7)
    )
ELSE
    SELECT 
      [TT].[ID],
      [TT].[Title]
    FROM [TargetTable] AS [TT]
    WHERE 1=2 -- Or any invalid filter, to retain the empty result
```

And then, because there are now 2 branches through your stored procedure, you should add `WITH RECOMPILE` to the stored proc, because the 2 branches have radically different query plans.

**Edit**

Just to clarify the comments:

Note that placing `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` after a query means that the [query plan is never cached](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/using-the-option-recompile-option-for-a-statement/) - this might not be a good idea if your query is called frequently.

The `WITH RECOMPILE` at a PROC level prevents caching of branches through the proc. It is **not** the same as `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` at query level.

If there are a large number of permutations of filter in your query, then the 'branching' technique above doesn't scale very well - your code quickly becomes unmaintainable.

You might unfortunately then need to consider using [parameterized dynamic SQL](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/160031/best-method-to-implement-a-filtered-search). SQL will then at least cache a separate plan for each permutation.

Comment: @StuartLC, I update the question before, the script is just a simple sample, I have more local variables and the mix of them in where clause, so I can't use the `if` statement before the main query, it's more complex as you think, but still this is a solution.

Comment: @SaeidAlizade:- As I mentioned in my answer this may be because of using local variables in your where clause. It causes FULL TABLE SCAN